# Copying values from a range with added header and sorting by size in Excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a table ranging from B5 to R20, every row has a header and not every cell in range (except headers) has values. Table looks like this:
John   empty  empty  2    5   300...
Steve  empty  23     45   130...
Todd   100    123    150  170...
...
Names are headers and instead of zeros there are empty cells. I need to copy these values in a new column (column AJ) and I need to copy the appropriate header next to every value (header value goes in column AI). After the copy those two columns should be sorted descending by AJ column. I have this so far:

```
Sub Sorter()

Dim g As Integer
Dim sourceCol As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim sourceCol1 As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim t As Integer

sourceCol = 35
sourceCol1 = sourceCol + 1
rowCount = 300

t = 5
    For g = 1 To 16
            Set rng1 = Range(Rows(t).Cells(3), Rows(t).Cells(18))
            If rng1.Cells(g) > 0 Then

            For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
                currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
                If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
                    Cells(t, 2).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Cells(t, g).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Cells(currentRow, sourceCol1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            Next currentRow
            End If
            t = t + 1
        Next g

' This part sorts the two columns
Columns("AI:AJ").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "AJ1:AJ300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("AI1:AJ300")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Kraj:
End Sub
```

So, the sorting part is working, but the copying part is giving me problems. I'm stuck so can you please help?
The result should be:

```
    AI     AJ
    John   300
    Todd   170
    Todd   150
    Steve  130
    ... etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution to test.

```
Sub Sorter()
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim sourceCol As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim targetrow As Long
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim sourceCol1 As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim t As Integer

    sourceCol = 35
    sourceCol1 = sourceCol + 1
    rowCount = 300
    targetrow = 1
    t = 5
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        While .Cells(t, 1) <> ""
            For g = 2 To 17
                If .Cells(t, g) > 0 Then
                    targetrow = targetrow + 1
                    .Cells(targetrow, sourceCol) = .Cells(t, 1)
                    .Cells(targetrow, sourceCol1) = .Cells(t, g)
                End If
            Next g
            t = t + 1
        Wend
        ' This part sorts the two columns
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AJ1:AJ300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("AI1:AJ300")
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I used my solution for sorting and I changed a few numbers but the code is everything I needed. Thank you very much for this!